# How to design this asynchronus callbacks

Tags: java, oop, asynchronous

I have a problem with designing my three classes, which are:
**UserManager** - retreive data from server using sessionManager
**SessionManger** - handles web session and requests on web server using WebRequest, autologin user when there is idle time between request bigger than maximum allowed
**WebRequest** - POST data to website and returns it's response (this is asynchronous class)

```
// Posts dat to web server and returns response using Interface
public class WebRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, byte[]> {
    interface DoneInterface {
        void onSuccess(byte []data);
        void onError(Exception e, String message);
    };
  // Sets interface to be called when request from server is done
  public void onDone(DoneInterface callable)
  // Requests data from server
  public boolean PostUrl(String url);

  // ... other methods, variables
}

// Handles auto login of user 
public class SessionManager {
    private WebRequest webRequest = null;

    // Creates request on web server, "callback" is interface that should be called when 
    // WebRequest instance is done with downloading response    
    public void Request(String url, HashMap data, WebRequest.DoneInterface callback) {
    webRequest.onDone(new WebRequest.DoneInterface() {    
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(byte[] data) {
        // HERE I NEED TO DO SOME ACTION BEFORE CALLING callback.onSuccess 
        // that was passed as argument and will process data     

        callback.onSuccess(data);               
      }

      @Override
      public void onError(Exception e, String message) {
        // IF error, we will need to crate new session probalby
        sandManager = null;

        // Call callback (interface) passed as argument
        callback.onError(e, message);
      }
    });
    webRequest.PostUrl(url);
  }
  // ... other methods, variables
}

// Main class
class User {
  private SessionManager session = new SessionManager();

  public SomeMethod() {
    session.Request(new WebRequest.DoneInterface() {    
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(byte[] data) {
        // Here I need to process data received from web server                     
      }

      @Override
      public void onError(Exception e, String message) {}
    });
  }
}
```

**I'm getting this error** `Cannot refer to a non-final variable "callback" inside an inner class defined in a different method` (SessionManager, *callback.onSuccess(data);* line). I know that is because "callback" variable isn't `final`. But **how should I design this classes** so that I could **alter data** returned from WebRequest **inside SessionManager** before passing them to User ??

Comment: You need to do what it says, declare your method parameters as `final`.

Comment: Nothing seems to prevent you from doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that even if you make the variable `final`. `final` only means that you can't assign a new value to the local variable. That's to eliminate confusion for if a local varible is put in an inner class and then changes. If you don't need to repoint `callback` to a new callback, `final` will not restrict you. Just make it `final`, and trust me, everything will be all right.